# How to loop through and clean a recursive array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling with the final step on a function that I am writing to clean up a multi-dimensional array.  I want the function to loop through the array (and any sub-arrays) and then return a cleaned array.

Whilst I can use `array_walk_recursive` to output the cleaned data, I'm struggling with returning the data as an array in the same structure as the inputted.  Can anyone help?  Any help greatly appreciated....

Here's my code:

```
function process_data($input){
    function clean_up_data($item, $key)
    {
        echo strip_tags($item) . ' '; // This works and outputs all the cleaned data
        $key = strip_tags($item);     // How do I now output as a new array??
        return strip_tags($item);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($input, 'clean_up_data');
}

$array = process_data($array);  // This would be the ideal usage
print_r($array);  // Currently this outputs nothing
```

Comment: You want to return an array with all the "$key"s (not multidimensional) array?

Comment: [Official document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) has a nice example for you to follow.

Comment: how about _not_ wrapping a function definition in a callable function and just use `&$item, &$key` in your callback ([check the examples in the manual](http://www.php.net/array_walk_recursive)). This is where references might just prove useful

Comment: @djot I would like to return the array with the same multidimensional structure as inputted.  All the function would do is clean the data...

Comment: Thank you @Alireza Fallah  Problem now solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `array_walk_recursive` like that :

```
<?php
$arr = array(...);
function clean_all($item,$key)
{
$item = strip_tags($item);
}
array_walk_recursive($arr , 'clean_all');
?>
```

OR :

this is a recursive function , i think it solves your problem :

```
<?php
    function clean_all($arr)
    {
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
    {
       if(is_array($value)) $arr[$key] = clean_all($value);
       else  $arr[$key] = strip_tags($value);
    }
    return $arr;
    }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the value by reference

```
function clean_up_data(&$item, $key)
```